# Windows SSH-Server is only reading first line from "authorized_keys" file

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

I am trying to SSH from Ubuntu(WSL) to Windows but the OpenSSH-Server on Windows seems to be reading only the first line of authorized_keys file.

- When I put the SSH-Key I use to SSH from Ubuntu to Windows first in authorized_keys file then I am able to SSH correctly. I'm prompted for SSH Key password 'coz my SSH key is password protected.
- When I put that SSH on second line in authorized_keys file I am prompted to enter Windows user account password, instead of SSH key password

Windows OpenSSH version

`OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3`

Ubuntu OpenSSH version

`OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

Comment: If you need our assistance setting up OpenSSH you will have to provide your configuration file at a minimum

Comment: And versions...

Comment: I've updated the question. check for the versions there.